# Delay in a threaded function response

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, events, concurrency

I am trying to replicate ES6 events behavior in python, so I wrote the following code:

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class Event:
    def __init__(self, action):
        self.action= action
        self.flag = False
        self.__watchFlag()
    def triggerAction(self):
        self.flag = True
    def __watchFlag(self):
        if self.flag:
            self.action()
            self.flag = False
        Thread(target=self.__watchFlag).start()


def action():
    print("Event triggered action.")
    
my_event = Event(action)

my_event.triggerAction()
```

Which works just fine *except* when I try to trigger the action two times consecutively, i.e:

```py
my_event.triggerAction()
my_event.triggerAction()
```

Only 1 event is triggered, but if I add a `sleep(1/10)` in between each trigger, works well. So I am assuming there is a delay somewhere in the process, any ideas?

**NOTE:** PLS DON'T RECOMMEND ANY EVENTS LIBRARIES ALREADY EXISTING IN PYTHON, I KNOW THEM, THIS IS NOT MY END GOAL, THX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your code to:

```
def triggerAction(self):
    print("setting to true")
    self.flag = True
```

when you have:

```
my_event.triggerAction()
my_event.triggerAction()
```

you get the following output:

```
setting to true
setting to true
Event triggered action.
```

But if you have :

```
my_event.triggerAction()
sleep(1/10)
my_event.triggerAction()
```

you got:

```
setting to true
Event triggered action.
setting to true
Event triggered action.
```

So in the first case you set flag to `true` *immediately*, so you don't given enough time for the context switch to kick in.